# I can't fetch documents from the downloads folder in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to attach documents from download folder. But i am getting the error 
"java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DownloadReact-native commands.pdf (No such file or directory)".Here i show the code that i used to get path.

```
 if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                    Log.d("build_version_one", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT.toString())
                    Log.d("build_version_two", Build.VERSION_CODES.M.toString())

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        val id: String
                        var cursor: Cursor? = null
                        try {
                            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME), null, null, null)
                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                                val fileName = cursor.getString(0)
                               // val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/" + fileName
                                val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/Download" + fileName
                                val ss = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("").toString()+"/Download" + fileName

                                Log.d("orginal_path","one"+path)
                                Log.d("orginal_path","two"+ss)

                                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                                    Log.d("orginal_path","working")
                                    return path
                                }
                            }
                        } finally {
                            cursor?.close()
                        }
                        id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
                            if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                                return id.replaceFirst("raw:".toRegex(), "")
                            }
                            val contentUriPrefixesToTry = arrayOf(
                                    "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                                    "content://downloads/my_downloads"
                            )
                            for (contentUriPrefix in contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                                return try {
                                    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id))
                                    Log.d("orginal_content_uri", contentUri.toString())
                                    /*   final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                                            Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));*/
                                    getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
                                } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                                    //In Android 8 and Android P the id is not a number
                                    uri.path.replaceFirst("^/document/raw:", "").replaceFirst("^raw:", "")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Exception states, there is no such file/directory available on your disk or path provided is incorrect.

At the first glance, it seems you missed a slash between filename and Download directory `/storage/emulated/0/DownloadReact-native commands.pdf`. Make sure you have a slash between filename and a path.

```
val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/Download/" + fileName
val ss = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("").toString()+"/Download/" + fileName
```

See if it works. Otherwise verify if you file in the respective directory.

Answer (score 0):

`getExternalStorageDirectory` deprecated in API level 29 java. Use `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`, or `getExternalMediaDir()` (methods on Context).